# Problem based on extension of Dedekind Domain

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be a Dedekind domain with field of fraction $K$, let $L|K$ be a finite separable extension of $K$ and $\mathcal{O}_L$ be the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_K$ in $L$. Then show that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is again Noetherian.

My effort : Actually this is a part of theorem given in Algebraic Number Theory by NEUKRICH.

To show $\mathcal{O}_L$  noetherian I have to check that every ideal of $\mathcal{O}_L$ is finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_L$ module. Now I understood that $\mathcal{O}_L\subset M$, where $M$ is finitely generated free $\mathcal{O}_K$ module of rank $n=[L:K]$ and also for any ideal of $\mathcal{O}_L$ say $I$ then $I \subset \mathcal{O}_L \subset M$ and we know that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is noetherian   and $I$ is $\mathcal{O}_K$ submodule but using this how I conclude that $I$ is finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_L$ module. Any help/hint in this regards would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: With a noetherian ring, every submodule of a finitely generated module is also finitely generated. So $I$ is finitely generated as a $\mathcal{O}_K$-module. It is therefore finitely generated as a $\mathcal{O}_L$-module.

Comment: Here $M$ is isomorphic with $n$ times direct sum of $\mathcal{O}_K$ and as $\mathcal{O}_K$ is noetherian so $M$ is also noetherian $\mathcal{O}_K$ module. Now $I$ is $\mathcal{O}_K$ submodule of noetherian $\mathcal{O}_K$ module $M$. Hence $I$ is finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_K$ module and rest of the argument is true as $\mathcal{O}_K \subset \mathcal{O}_L $.